# How to change the display of a url with a port number using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For example, let's say I have the url example.com:8000

When the user enters the url subdomain.example.com it redirects to example.com:8000

The only problem I have is that the displayed URL shows example.com:8000 after the redirect instead of subdomain.example.com

Is there a way using .htaccess to keep the url displayed as subdomain.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

No. .htaccess rewrite rules can only change the server's interpretation of a URL; they can't change the way a URL appears to the client.

Comment: Isn't .htaccess used commonly to do this though?  For example, removing .php from the end of URLs

Comment: figured it out: http://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server